# Why is my JSON code in Swift not parsing?

Tags: json, swift, parsing, swiftui

Disclaimer: Very basic question below. I am trying to learn the basics of IOS development.

I'm currently trying to parse data from an API to a SwiftUI project and am not able to successfully do so.

The code goes as follows:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Poem: Codable {
    let title, author: String
    let lines: [String]
    let linecount: String
}

class FetchPoem: ObservableObject {
  // 1.
  @Published var poems = [Poem]()
     
    init() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://poetrydb.org/random/1")!
        // 2.
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let poemData = data {
                    // 3.
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Poem].self, from: poemData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.poems = decodedData
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
        
    @ObservedObject var fetch = FetchPoem()
    
    let joined = fetch.poem.lines.joined(separator: "\n")
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(fetch.poem.title)
            .padding()
        Text( \(joined) )
            .padding()
    
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The build currently fails. It's throwing me the following errors:

```
Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Binding<Subject>' conform to 'StringProtocol'

Referencing subscript 'subscript(dynamicMember:)' requires wrapper 'ObservedObject<FetchPoem>.Wrapper'

Value of type 'FetchPoem' has no dynamic member 'poem' using key path from root type 'FetchPoem'
```

Moreover, I am attempting to append the array "Lines" into one main String variable "Joined". However, I am not sure this works... The error is "String interpolation can only appear inside a string literal". Would love some help if anyone knows...

Any ideas? All help is appreciated.

---

** Edited Code - Q2

```
import SwiftUI

struct Poem: Codable, Hashable {
    let title, author: String
    let lines: [String]
    let linecount: String
}

class FetchPoem: ObservableObject {

  @Published var poems = [Poem]()
     
    func getPoem() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://poetrydb.org/random/1")!
        // 2.
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let poemData = data {
                    // 3.
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Poem].self, from: poemData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.poems = decodedData
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
        
    @ObservedObject var fetch = FetchPoem()
        
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                if let poem = fetch.poems.first {
                    Button("Refresh") {getPoem}
                    Text("\(poem.author): \(poem.title)").bold()
                    Divider()
                    ScrollView {
                        VStack {
                            ForEach(poem.lines, id: \.self) {
                                Text($0)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you wanted this (because `poems` is an array) - tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

```
struct Poem: Codable, Hashable {
    let title, author: String
    let lines: [String]
    let linecount: String
}

// ...

struct ContentView: View {
        
    @ObservedObject var fetch = FetchPoem()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(fetch.poems, id: \.self) {
                Text("\($0.author): \($0.title)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... , and next might be wrapping that into `NavigationView/NavigationLink` with shown each poem in desination view.

Of showing lines as follows:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if let poem = fetch.poems.first {
            Text("\(poem.author): \(poem.title)").bold()
            Divider()
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(poem.lines, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks so much. Incredibly helpful suggestion... One last question: How would you suggest including a Refresh button to this? I attempted Button("Refresh") {FetchPoem} above the Author Name without success.

Comment: Move everything from `init` to FetchPoem to separated function, eg. `fetch`, which you will be able to call and from `init` for initial poem retrieving, and from view button to retrieve next random poem.

Comment: Would it look something like the Edited Code above?  Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: I'll post a new one... Thanks anyways